# How to extract patches from a .tiff file to feed as input to Alexnet implemented in Keras?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to use transfer learning to extract features. My dataset has images in .tiff format.How do I feed patches of this format to the Alexnet implemented in Keras ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to feed any other format of data to ALextNet or do you need complete guide to feed images into a neural network in Keras. If you are able to feed a numpy array containing the pixel values of images then you can follow the following steps to read a tiff image and convert a numpy array out of it. Or if you want a complete tutorial then you should mention it in the question.

**Using PIL library**

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('a_image.tif')
```

**Using matplotlib**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
I = plt.imread(tiff_file)
```

Let us know if you need any help with it.